# Can we call event in laravel before expiring the login user session?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to store logout datetime of user for that i have created event which works fine after clicking on logout button Listeners event is called. Below i have written code to store logout time.

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\UserTrack;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoggedOutListener
{
    public function handle($event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;
        $user = Auth::user();
        $track = UserTrack::where('user_id','=',$user->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $end = $track->last_logout = Carbon::now();
        $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $track->last_login);;
        $track->timestamp = $start->diffInSeconds($end);
        $track->save();
    }
}
```

I want to call that event before expiring session to store the logout time.

Comment: I think not.
At most you can track when a user tries to access some resource but his session has expired.
From PHP you have no control when the user closes the browser

Comment: You can use websockets to periodically ping pong from server to client. If it does not respond (browser closed or maybe connection was disconnected) you can fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

you add a middleware to the logout route :

```
<?php

...

Route::get('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
            ->middleware([RegisterLogoutEventMiddleware::class])
            ->name('logout');
```

and create your middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 
class RegisterLogoutEventMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        event(LogoutEvent::class);
 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

after that you can create the `LogoutEvent` event and register it in `EventServiceProvider` :

```
protected $listen = [
    ...
    LogoutEvent::class => [
        LoggedOutListener::class,
    ],
];
```